# getting the times of trying the loop

Tags: java

My Dr was telling me to figure out how many times did the user tried to get the correct answer, it really confused me. Here's the program. Please someone help me get this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");
    int answer = s.nextInt();
    while (answer != (a + b)) { ///tell him it's wrong
        System.out.println("Incorrect. Try again.");
        System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");  
        answer = s.nextInt();
    } 
        System.out.println("Correct.");
        /// how many tries did the user tried? H.W
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a variable to count the number of times the loop worked.!!

Answer (score 0):

Just have one `count` variable and then increase it inside while loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");
    int answer = s.nextInt();
    while (answer != (a + b)) { ///tell him it's wrong
        System.out.println("Incorrect. Try again.");
        count++; //increase if the number of wrong answers
        System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");  
        answer = s.nextInt();
    } 
    System.out.println("Correct after " + count + " time(s)");
}
```

Comment: Why exactly did we used the count? it's not clear to me

Comment: the count variable is declared outside the look, got increased inside the loop, and is used outside the loop in print statement

Answer (score 0):

You can take a variable initially set to 0 say `count` and increment it with each execution of the `while` loop i.e whenever the user is incorrect. Outside the loop you can print the number of tries as `count`.

In codes you can do it like this..

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

    int count = 0; // setting variable to count number of tries
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");
    int answer = s.nextInt();

    while (answer != (a + b)) { ///tell him it's wrong
        System.out.println("Incorrect. Try again.");
        count++; // incrementing the number of tries i.e count
        System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");  
        answer = s.nextInt();
    } 

    System.out.println("Correct after " + count + " time(s)"); // displaying count
    /// how many tries did the user tried? H.W
    }

}
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");
    int answer = s.nextInt();
    int count = 0;
    while (answer != (a + b)) { ///tell him it's wrong
        count++; // Why count ??
        System.out.println("Incorrect. Try again."); 
        System.out.println("What is: " + a + " + " + b + " ?");  
        answer = s.nextInt();
    } 
        System.out.println("Correct. It took you " + count + "attempt/s.");
        /// how many tries did the user tried? H.W

    }
}
```

I saw your comment for above answer. The answer is 100% correct.

Now coming to your question about use of `count`.

Tell me how would you do it manually.? If you ask a question to your friend and s/he tried 4 times and then got the correct answer at last attempt i.e. 5th attempt, then how will you tell him/her "Oh you took 5 attempts..!" ??

You would count it on your finger tips each time s/he answers (until the correct guess), right?

Exactly what you do it by code, you start/initialize a variable to `zero` ( 0 ) and as you get the input from user (i.e answer) you check if it is correct or not... if it is correct you would increase the count value by 1 (open up your first finger and say "hey you took 1 attempt"), if it is wrong you would (open up your finger and say "No, try again.") increase the counter by 1, and again and again keep increasing the counter on every wrong attempt. And if answer matches, you would increase the counter and say "Hurrah.. you got correct answer and took `count` times."

Hope you got your query solved. !!

Comment: Understood, thank you sir you've been a great support <3